# Angular primeng drop down with float label render badly on first time

Tags: angular, primeng

I have an angular application in where im using floating labels
when i first load the component (a p-dialog) the floating labels are "falling down" to the select as shown in the image
[image]

here is the code im using

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
  <span class="ui-float-label">
    <p-dropdown [options]="categories" formControlName="category" [style]="{ width: '100%' }"></p-dropdown>
    <label>{{ 'products.category-name' | translate }}</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

this form is generated using the formBuilder and what i noticed is that if i call form.reset(), then on the next time the module is rendered nicely.
Im not sure what is the source of the problem
any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be related to the fact that when filling the form using patchValue or setValue, the dropdown filled property is not set to true
you have to set it manually in the meanwhile

here is how

```
<p-dropdown [options]="invoiceStatus" formControlName="status" [style]="{ width: '100%' }" #ddStatus></p-dropdown>
```

and in the controller

```
@ViewChild('ddStatus')
  ddStatus: Dropdown;
```

and later when setting a value to the form call set the filled property this way
this.ddStatus.filled = true;
i hope they will fix it soon

Comment: Why not use `dropdown.updateFilledState()` instead?
I believe this is a better practice.

Comment: @j4v1 either way should work, but only if you add the following: setTimeout(() => this.ddStatus.updateFilledState(), 600);

Answer (score 6):

Please use like this;

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
  <span class="ui-float-label">
    <p-dropdown [autoDisplayFirst]="false" [options]="categories" formControlName="category" [style]="{ width: '100%' }"></p-dropdown>
    <label>{{ 'products.category-name' | translate }}</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

and see **autoDisplayFirst** (Whether to display the first item as the label if no placeholder is defined and the value is null.) definition in https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown

**autoDisplayFirst** is **true** by default. Therefore, it displays the first item as the label if no placeholder is defined and the value is null.And it overlaps with **float-label**.

Comment: This solution is much cleaner than the accepted one.
This option makes sense anyways, since the dropdown also does not seem to set the inital value for a form control if the first one is displayed, which causes e.g. validation errors if the control is required and no other option is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the cause is but you could try to put a @ViewChild() on your dropdown and call the updateFilledState() method on it.

Answer (score 0):

Your label rendered on top of the drop down. The float label CSS that you are working with either isn't' set up for a p-dropdown (as opposed to an input, or a select)

Comment: if i close the dialog and than reopen it, than its rendering fine

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this

```
 <div class="ui-g-12">
  <span class="ui-float-label">
    <p-dropdown [options]="categories" formControlName="category" [style]="{ width: '100%' }">
<ng-template pTemplate="item" let-option> <span>{{option.label || 'Select a contact type'}}</span> </ng-template>
</p-dropdown>
    <label>{{ 'products.category-name' | translate }}</label>
  </span>
</div>
```

make your null valued option **label** to "".